# Java changes reference but not the object itself?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, pass-by-reference

Please see the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test t1 = new Test();
    t1.i = 1;
    Test t0 = t1;
    Test t2 = new Test();
    t2.i = 2;
    t0 = t2; 
    System.out.println(t1.i); //prints 1, I thought it would print 2
}
```

Is there any way to change t1 object after I got it from somewhere else by simple assignment without accessing t1 directly? (i.e. t1 = t0)

Comment: "Is there any way to change t1 object after I got it from somewhere else by simple assignment without accessing t1 directly?" no, you can reassign reference only with `=` operator like `reference = otherInstance`, so if you want to `t1` to contain instance from `t0` your only choice is `t1 = t0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an illustration of your program and what it does. Each state of the system is shown separated by a dashed line.

Note what happens when you do `t0 = t1`. You assumed that this means that from now on, `t0` and `t1` are synonyms - whenever you use one, the other is affected. But in fact, `t0` and `t1` are simply two references to the same object.

Making a new assignment to `t0` simply detached it from the "blue" object and re-attached it to the "violet" object.

As long as `t0` and `t1` were both pointing at the same object, any changes you make in the content of their pointed object (such as `t0.i = 5`) would be seen by the other reference, because they both refer to the same object. But as soon as you assign something else to `t0`, it loses its connection to `t1`. After you do that, changing it will be reflected in `t2`, which points to the same, "violet" object, not in `t1` which still points to the old, "blue" one.

So:

- If you assign a new value to the reference - it no longer points to the same object as before, and any previous "double referencing" is lost.
- If you assign a new value to the *content* of the reference, it will be reflected in all reference variables that look at the same object.

[image: This is an illustration of your program]

Answer (score 1):

What you did not understand here is that when doing `t0 = t2` you replace the adress reference of `t0` which is at that time the same as `t1` by the reference of `t2` so no, it won't affect `t1`.

However, `t0.i` would print 2.

But to answer your question

> Is there any way to change t1 object after I got it from somewhere else
>   by simple assignment without accessing t1 directly? (i.e. t1 = t0)

Yes there is a way, check this snippet

```
Test t1 = new Test();
t1.i = 1;
Test t0 = t1;
t0.i = 3;
System.out.println(t1.i); //prints 3
```

This will modify `t1.i` to `3` accessing `t0.i`

If you want to do it using the `t2` object, then you can modify the value of `i` directly :

```
Test t1 = new Test();
t1.i = 1;
Test t0 = t1;
Test t2 = new Test();
t2.i = 2;
t0.i = t2.i; 
System.out.println(t1.i); //prints 2
```

Comment: But what if the Test object is much more complex than holding just a single integer, I don't think it's reasonable to assign each member explicitly (imagine for example that one day someone will add new membar b to Test class, it won't be copied to to t1)

Comment: @Niros I agree with you, I just wanted to show the possibilities and an explanation of why your snippet did not return what you expected. However, a possibility to fix the example in your comment would consists of keeping each object in an Array, then to reassign you could do `arrayOfObjectT[3] = newObjectT`;

Answer (score 1):

```
Test t1 = new Test();
t1.i = 1
```

can be represented as

```
            +-------+
            | Test  |
t1 -------> +-------+
            | i (1) |
            +-------+
```

now when you do

```
Test t0 = t1;
```

You are assigning to `t0` same value as value from `t1`, which means that now they hold same value (address to same Test instance), so your situation is

```
            +-------+
t1 ----+    | Test  |
       +--> +-------+
t0 ----+    | i (1) |
            +-------+
```

Now after this code

```
Test t2 = new Test();
t2.i = 2;
```

you will have

```
            +-------+
t1 ----+    | Test  |
       +--> +-------+
t0 ----+    | i (1) |
            +-------+

            +-------+
            | Test  |
t2 -------> +-------+
            | i (2) |
            +-------+
```

and when you do

```
t0 = t2;
```

you change your situation to

```
            +-------+
t1 ----+    | Test  |
       +--> +-------+
            | i (1) |
t0 ----+    +-------+
       |
       |    +-------+
       |    | Test  |
t2 ----+--> +-------+
            | i (2) |
            +-------+
```

so as you see now `t0` holds same object as object held by `t2` reference, but `t1` reference wasn't changed, and that is why

```
System.out.println(t1.i)
```

prints `1`.